# IOS7 Date picker Probleme with setFrame

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, uikit, uidatepicker

IOS 7 simple problem with frame

```
Viewdidappear
CGRect frameView = _myDateView.frame;
CGRect framePicker = _myBirsthDayPicker.frame;

framePicker.origin.y = -83.0f;
frameView.size.height = 50.0f;

[_myDateView setFrame:frameView]; is OK
[_myBirsthDayPicker setFrame:framePicker]; is not ok
```

And when i do my one only one, it works ????

Comment: Are you taking into account that the frame of the picker is related to its container view?

Comment: my PickerDateView is a child view of DateView